# Jquery Traverse DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

I have the following code:

```
<p class="represent">Representing</p>
<div class="clients_wrap">
    <ul class="clients">
        <li><img src="{{ client.get_sized_image }}"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This chunk is repeated a number of times. The number of list items may vary between 0 and 10+, but if it is 0 then I need to hide the p.represent tag that precedes it – this needs to be independant for each repeated code block.

I've tried a number of things but can't quite figure it out e.g.

```
function hideEmptyClients() {
    if ( $('ul.clients li').length >= 1 ) {
        $('ul.clients').parent().closest('p').hide();
    }
}
$(function() {
    hideEmptyClients();
});
```

SOLVED:
Best solution provided by Tomalak:

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.clients:not(:has(li))').closest(".represent_wrap").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the logic you have seems backwards to what you describe - you're hiding the `p` element if there are multiple `li` elements found, not if there are none. Secondly, `closest()` looks at parent elements, where as the `p` is a sibling of the `div`, so you'd need to use `prev()` instead. Try this:

```
$('.clients').each(function() {
    var $ul = $(this);
    if (!$('li', $ul).length) {
        $ul.closest('.clients_wrap').prev('p').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Textbook – thanks Rory. To help me learn can you explain this line please, it's a bit confusing, especially the bit with the li, ul: (!$('li', $ul).length)

Comment: That line is looking for `li` elements within the `ul`. The `!` inverts the condition, so it's effectively saying, if the number of `li` within the `ul` is 0, do the following....

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('p.represent').filter(function () {
        return $(this).next("clients_wrap").find("li").length === 0;
    }).hide();
});
```

The rationale behind this follows the jQuery paradigm:

1. select something (`$('p.represent')`)
2. optionally filter it (`.filter(...)`)
3. do something to it (`.hide()`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tomalak, I think I miscommunicated my aim but Rory pre-emptied my intent so all is sorted. Appreicate your time. Jon

Comment: @JonChubb Not sure where the mis-communication is - this does *exactly* what you describe. Quote *"if it is 0 then I need to hide the p"*.

Comment: @JonChubb For next time I recommend something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pDYMH/1/

Comment: WOW that's an awesome solution!

Comment: Just updated the intital question with your solution – cheers :)